# Android fragments when to introduce them into the application

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I'm making an project that needs to run on tablets as well as phones.
I was thinking to use fragments for this. but i dont have any history in using them.

Should I implement them right away or is it easy to implement them later on?
( i could first make the working phone app and later on make it an tablet app)

someone with an history in implementing fragments for the first time?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use fragments from the beginning for UI components which may be used in a master-detail like fashon on tablets but as single activity on the smaller phone. You will get a light overhead for the smaller phone (e.g. using an activity container exactly one fragment) but you will profit from that overhead when switching to the tablet. It will also improve a consistent UI design between smaller phones and tablets.

If you target pre-fragment (e.g. Android 2.x) devices use the support library. I also recomment to mark the classes depending on the support library using comments. This way you will find them easier when switching from the support library to the "native" implementation sometimes in the future (at least you have modify the import statements, because the support library uses different packages. In rare instance you will have to modify methods (e.g. change `getSupportFragmentManager()` to `getFragmentManager()`).

Answer (score 1):

I have been working for two weeks to update an android application and make it using fragment, so it will be easier for you to use directly Fragment. But i think that the question that you must ask your self is did i need fragments in my app???

Essentially, Fragments allow you to show the user multiple 'activities' at one time. Did you need this?? if no it will be easier that you use resource qualifiers to point to another layout with more/less Fragments (ex. layout-land-large). You will be able to update the size of elements in your file.xml.

if you need to show two activities (when using tablet) , the best solution is using fragment. and here you say: Are the Fragments working together to provide the user a streamlined experience? If yes it will be perfect that you work directly with fragments because fragments send arguments between each other to communicate (not the same as activity).
In activity: intent.putExtra()
In fragment: you can use bundle for example. So if you need to update your application after you will waste your time searching for sender extras and sending it other wise.